# d3.js tab code completion in Sublime

Tags: d3.js, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

is it possible to have d3.js code completion in Sublime, so that when typing

```
d3.
```

it will show the available methods on d3

Comment: This is a little different than what you are looking for, but you should check out [this package](https://github.com/fabriciotav/d3-snippets-for-sublime-text-2) which has a lot of snippets for D3.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Should work out of the box so long as you have the d3 javascript files loaded / installed using bower.

Otherwise try [webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/) in trial mode :-)